# Ip whitelisting in AWS proxy API gateway using SAM template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

Im trying to create a ip whitelist to allow access to the APi gateway. I need to do it using the sam template. Could not find any documentation regarding this. Can anyone please point me out to anything related ?

Thanks

Comment: I'll wait for an expert in SAM to answer, but I see two ways to achieve that: 

1 - Applying IP restrictions through [API Gateway Authorizer](http://benfoster.io/blog/aws-api-gateway-ip-restrictions)

2 - Using [Cloudfront and WAF](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/what-is-aws-waf.html) to limit the API call from a Specific IP addresses.

I'm not sure if you can define that through CF or SAM template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `AWS_IAM` as your **Authorization** for your endpoint.

[image: AWS_IAM Example]

You can then create an IAM Policy like this which allows you to specify the IP Address.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "execute-api:Invoke"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "xxx.xx.xx.xx/32"
                }
            },
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:*:*:*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Article: http://benfoster.io/blog/aws-api-gateway-ip-restrictions

Comment: Thanks for your response. Im looking a way to do it using the sam template. Do you know whether its possible ?

Comment: Any resources regarding that ?

Comment: I can't think of any right now since I haven't tried it myself. But there should be a way to implement the above using SAM.

Answer (score 2):

The real problem isn't about white listing using AWS SAM template, but rather how do you do it all. Once you finalise a method in general, it can be generalised into a template. I personally think creating a **separate VPC for your API gateway** should be a good solution. Or you could **block traffic from within your application logic or AWS WAF**.

**EDIT** : Therefore, **No** I don't think it could be done just via a SAM template for API gateway resource.

Comment: Does that mean it cannot be done using the sam template ?

Comment: Since it can't be done with the API gateway Web console, I don't think SAM template would do any help :)